# Simon's Algorithm: Calculating the effects on the second Hadamard gate and the resulting amplitudes

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, hadamard, simons-algorithm

I am currently reading about Simon's algorithm in "An Introduction to Quantum
Computing" and stumbled over Exercise 6.5.1, that ask the reader to show that:

> Let $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \{0,1\}^n$ and let $s = x \oplus y$.
> Show that $$H^{\otimes n} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |x⟩ + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |y⟩ \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}} \sum_{\{z \mid z \cdot s = 0\} } (-1)^{x
>  \cdot z} |z⟩$$

I think I am close to showing this, but my amplitudes are off -- what am I missing in the below derivation?

We know that $H^{\otimes n}  |x⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩$

So we use that to derive:
$$ H^{\otimes n} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|x⟩ + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |y⟩ \right)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(H^{\otimes n} |x⟩ + H^{\otimes n} |y⟩\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩ + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{y \cdot z} |z⟩ \right) $$
We write the sum as one:
$$ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}} \left (\sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩ +  (-1)^{y \cdot z} |z⟩ \right) $$
We know use the fact that $y = x \oplus s$:
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}} \left( \sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩ +  (-1)^{(x \oplus s) \cdot z} |z⟩ \right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}} \left( \sum_{z \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩ +  (-1)^{(x \cdot z) \oplus (s \cdot z)} |z⟩ \right) $$
We write know that if $s \cdot z =1 $, the amplitudes cancel each other out, leaving only
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}} \left( \sum_{\{z \mid z \cdot s = 0\}} (-1)^{x \cdot z} |z⟩ +  (-1)^{(x \cdot z)} |z⟩ \right)$$
This is where I am stuck -- This should leave each of the remaining states $|z⟩$ with amplitude $2 \cdot (-1)^{x \cdot z}$, right? But this not match the result in the book nor do the amplitudes sum to one: The vector subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^n_2$, $\{z \in \{0,1\}^n \mid s \cdot z = 0\}$ has dimension $n-1$ and thus contain $2^{n-1}$ vectors, right? So the amplitudes would not sum to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake happens at the step "we write the sum as one", the normalization term ought to be $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2^n}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}$, not $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}}$.

Thus, the final state is:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\sum_{\{z|z\cdot s=0\}}(-1)^{x\cdot z}|z\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n-1}}}\sum_{\{z|z\cdot s=0\}}(-1)^{x\cdot z}|z\rangle
\end{align*}
$$